# How to build an antenna to receive VHF or UHF?

Tags: design, cubesat, radio-communication

I am trying to build a cubesat using a Raspberry Pi. I am now figuring out how to communicate with it. As far as I know, I understand I will have to use VHF or UHF to do so.

How do I decide on the frequency to use?

How will frquency affect the cost?

How do I build an antenna to receive the signals?

Where can I buy its components for the Pi?

Comment: There is a lot of literature and resources available just by googling. Please provide your research so far and make your question more specific.

Comment: The last question "where can I buy its components" unfortunately falls into the realm of endorsement, and so is not appropriate on this site.

Comment: I'd suggest searching around, for example: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/210822/lightweight-point-to-point-communication-protocols and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/103370/how-does-a-cube-sat-communicate-with-ground-station-with-a-1w-antenna for example. (These briefly mention possible frequencies and transceiver equipment and have site links.)

Comment: I think this question is on topic here, as satellite design and operation is part of the scope. It's only for an educational project, but there may be some people here who can help with background such as comms protocols, etc. The questioner should add more detail about the nature of the project though, to attract better answers.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I shall update my question with my findings soon

Comment: [This](https://funcube.org.uk/) and especially [this](http://www.funcubedongle.com/) look "fun"!

Comment: [It's OK to answer your own question](http://space.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I suggest you go to your local library and get some books related to amateur radio, and/or contact your national amateur radio association. Even if you do not get a license of your own (it may however help), those will cover a huge fraction of what you'll need to know in terms of radio communication basics, including propagation, antenna construction and transmission mode selection, *and* will be written not assuming you know everything up front. Also contact your local [AMSAT](http://www.amsat.org/). For specific questions about radio communications, feel free to head on over to [ham.se] SE.